# Alter these wordpress/woocommerce jquery scripts to display an alternate header logo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

I wanted the woocommerce pages in this WordPress site to show an alternative header logo than the rest of the site, so I had someone write javascript scripts to accomplish this.

Here is that set of scripts, which work perfectly. Every woocommerce page shows the alternate logo.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var url      = window.location.href;var cus_url = "example.com/woocommerce-shop-page/";
if(url == cus_url){
jQuery('img#logo').attr('src', 'example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/altlogo.png');
}
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
var url      = window.location.href;var cus_url = "example.com/woocommerce-shop-page/";
if(url == cus_url){
jQuery('img#logo').attr('src', 'example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/altlogo.png');
}
});
</script>

<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
jQuery('body.woocommerce-page img#logo').attr('src', 'example.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/01/altlogo.png');
});
</script>
```

THE PROBLEM:  I need to add more pages to the site that also display this alternative logo – but since they aren't specifically woocommerce pages, the alternative logo does not display.

I know almost nothing about Javascript, but I thought if I created a new page, made it a child of the woocommerce shop page, and added a wildcard character "*" to the end of the URL in the first script above, it would work:

It does not.

My hope is that there's some way to make ANY page that I designate a child of the woocommerce shop page display the alternative logo:

```
example.com/woocommerce-shop-page/any-child-page
```

Any hints as to what to do (how to properly alter these scripts, new scripts, or another approach altogether) would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it can be as simple as checking if the current href contains the woocommerce part rather than it has to exactly match the uri

```
if(url.indexOf('woocommerce-shop-page') > -1) {
 ... set logo ...
```

Comment: That sounds logical, I just don't know how to implement it.